# c++ arrays, how to add a new row of values in the same array?

Tags: c++, arrays

how do you create a new row of values in an array from user input or cin?

say theres a row of values already in the array and you need to add a second row of values
but not added to the first row, and how would you put the braces and the comma in, does the user put it in or is there something that will automatically put the bracers and comma in

```
int test [] = { 1, 21, 771, 410, 120711 },
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Comment: Maybe you should use a `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Without very bad and dirty tricks this is not possible. Better use list or vector (which is the nearest to an array). The other possibility is to use pointers and to extend it create a temporary memory, copy the old data and then add the new.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for a two-dimensional array.  This is declared like this:

```
int test[][5] = {
    {1, 21, 771, 410, 120711},
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
    // Add more if you want.
};
```

The first array is accessed through `test[0]`, the second through `test[1]`, etc. The first element of the first array is `test[0][0]`, the second `test[0][1]` and so forth.

Note that this is an array with a static size. You can't change it at runtime. If you know in advance how many rows you need, you just declare it as:

```
int test[NUMBER OF ROWS][NUMBER OF COLUMNS];
```

and then fill it with values later. But you cannot change the size. If you want a fully dynamic array, then you should use a vector of vectors:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > test;
```

You then add rows with:

```
test.push_back(std::vector<int>());
```

and add elements to each row with:

```
// Adds a number to the first row.
test[0].push_back(some_int);
```

Access happens the same way as with the static array (`test[0]`, `test[0][0]`, etc.)

Comment: how would it be added from user input or cin?

Comment: @user1887092 This is an array with a static size. You can't change it at runtime. If you know in advance how many rows you need, you just declare it as `int test[NUMBER OF ROWS][NUMBER OF COLUMNS]` and fill the values later. But you cannot change the size.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the size of array while still preserving its contents. The only way to change the size of an array at all is to use the `new` operator to allocate dynamic memory to a pointer, but this will destroy any data the array previously held. If you want to have a re-sizable array, you should probably use `std::vector.`

Comment: The last sentence is a bit misleading. `std::vector` is not a resizable array, it manipulates an array under the hood.

Comment: @Marlon: Not misleading at all.  The problem is that your definition of array is too narrow.

Comment: Whatever the definition is, the point was not that vector **is** a re-sizable array but rather that you should use it if you **want** a re-sizable array.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Misleading. Arrays have a fixed size. A "resizable array" is like saying "4 wheeled bicycle".

Comment: @Marlon: Again, the problem is your definition.  In your mind, an array is a thing declared like this: `TYPENAME arrayname[size];` -- But that's just one specific type of array.  The term array is, and always has been a more abstract concept which is used in a much greater context than you seem to think it is limited to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're keen on using c++11 you can keep your initialiser lists with std::vector like so:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  // initialise
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> test = { { 1, 21, 771, 410, 120711 },
                                         { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } };

  // add new data from user
  test.push_back({9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1});
}
```