# Vector of Vectors of Structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am trying to make a 'table' of sorts to store stats or skill values for a game.
I originally tried to use a multi-dimensional array with structs, but I want to be able to add rows of data whenever. I did some research: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774091/c-arrays-how-to-add-a-new-row-of-values-in-the-same-array), and found that vectors are probably what I need.
I am now trying to make a vector of vectors of structs, to no avail. I'm not good with errors D:
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct Skills
    {
        string type;
        int value;
    };
    vector< vector<Skills> > statTable;
    statTable[0][0].type = "test";
    cout << statTable[0][0].type << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And here are errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SXGw.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Vector is empty, add elements into it.

Comment: Please add errors in your question not as a link (read docs on how to ask a question in SO).

Comment: I'm just going to keep saying this in the hope it will eventually have an effect: please don't post pictures of code, or of errors. They're text, you're writing in a text box, just paste the text. It's _easier_ and better in every possible way.

Comment: error told everything, you cannot use object of local type as argument of template, move definition of `Skills` before main function.

Comment: @rafix07 That was before C++11.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, i know. I wrote my answer after checking his .png with error messages, so he doesn't use compiler with c++11.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using an old compiler. In this case declare the structure outside main placing it for example in the global space.

```
struct Skills
{
    string type;
    int value;
};

int main()
{
    //...
```

After this declaration

```
vector< vector<Skills> > statTable;
```

the vector `statTable` is empty. So you may not use the subscript operator.

Instead declare the vector like

```
vector< vector<Skills> > statTable(1, std::vector<Skills>( 1 ) );
```

After that you may write

```
statTable[0][0].type = "test";
```

The same can be achieved also by the following code snippet

```
vector< vector<Skills> > statTable;
statTable.push_back(vector<Skills>());
statTable[0].push_back(Skills());

statTable[0][0].type = "test";
cout << statTable[0][0].type << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I compiled this code but it gives me no error, it was compiled successfully but gave me segmentation error because you have to fill in data correctly, So here is my solution

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    struct Skills
    {
        string type;
        int value;
    };
    vector< vector<Skills> > statTable;
    vector<Skills> v;
    Skills x;
    x.type = "test";
    v.push_back(x);
    statTable.push_back(v);
    cout << statTable[0][0].type << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps, I'm using C++ 98 btw.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses! Didnt realise I had to make the vector in the first place :P